# Как удалит символ ударения с строки, сохранив другие символы?

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Код удаляет ударения, но также заменяет букву "й" на букву "и".

```
text = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
var chars = text.Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) 
!=UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray();
string result = new string(chars).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
```

Comment: Сделай проверку на й.

Comment: Вообще, в юникоде есть два способа сделать ударения:

первый способ - это добавочный символ ударения (как в приведённой строке); то есть буква и знак ударения - два отдельных символа, хранящиеся в строке;второй способ - использовать юникодные символы с ударением (acute); то есть буква и ударение представляют собой один символ. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/54350aef-6ef7-4875-94ca-966f3f20a7bd/-?forum=fordesktopru

Comment: `text.Replace(" ́", "")`

Comment: Я просто решил проблему с помощью Replace(), но всё же это не очень хорошие решение.

Comment: сделай тогда с отдельной проверкой для й

Comment: Если нужно удалять один конкретный [знак ударения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA_.D1.83.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B5_Unicode), то `.Where(c => c != '\u0301')`. Если нужно удалять все диакритические символы, то случай с буквой `й` придётся обрабатывать вручную.